# How to show javascript on UI

Tags: c#, html

I have found a javascript code on internet which can show me the local time but now it is not showing up on my view, who can help me with it?

Javascipt code:

```
ourDate = new Date();
    result = document.write(ourDate.toLocaleString());
    $("#time").html(result);
```

View:

```
  <td>Time:</td>
  <td><span id="time"></span></td>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the javascript to check what result evaluates too? You could use the developer tools built into chrome or Firebug in Firefox. that should at least point you to where to start looking for the bug.

Comment: Did you include _JQuery_? Working [code](http://jsfiddle.net/BU5AQ/).

Answer (score 2):

if you haven't added jQuery then please add latest jQuery reference, you were using `document.write()` which always writes your variable to your view so no need to use `document.write()` when initializing any variable.

Replace this `result = document.write(ourDate.toLocaleString());`

with this:

`result = ourDate.toLocaleString();`

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BU5AQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
ourDate = new Date();
$("#time").html(ourDate.toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ourDate  = new Date();
var result =  ourDate .toLocaleString() ;
$("#time").html(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To shorten your JavaScript, try this:

```
$("#time").html(new Date().toLocaleString());
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/x4dLf/1/